# mysql sql_safe_update constant error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I try to update a table using an `INNER JOIN` like this (`dummy.ID` is set as primary key):

```
UPDATE dummy
INNER JOIN original
   ON dummy.FirstName =original.FirstName
   AND dummy.LastName = original.LastName
SET dummy.col1 = original.col1
WHERE dummy.ID <> 0;
```

Having `SQL_SAFE_UPDATE` activated, and not being alowed to disable it in any way, for the above statement i get the famous error: `You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column`.

I've tried `WHERE KEY IN (,)`, `WHERE KEY NOT NULL`, and alot of other ways to implement the `WHERE` clause, but everything failed with the same error. The only way it worked was using `WHERE dummy.ID = 1`, but this, of course, updates only one row.

Could it be because i use a `JOIN`? Is there any way to do this update without disabling  `sql_safe_update`?

Comment: Well is the `ID` column a key?

Comment: yep, stated in my post that it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer, so i will post as answer if anyone else has the same problem as myself.
The problem was the usage of `JOIN`, for some reason the compiler identifies that as a wrong-used `WHILE` in terms of `sql_safe_update`.

```
UPDATE dummy
SET col1 = 
(
    SELECT col1 FROM original
    WHERE dummy.FirstName = original.FirstName
        AND dummy.LastName = original.LastName
)
WHERE dummy.ID <> 0;
```